# jQuery load() method return a blank or null element permenantly

Tags: jquery, load

When I run my code the part of page containing this `#scroll` element becomes blank. I have tested various elements and the results are always the same. Any suggestions?

```js
$("#scroll").load(" #scroll > *");
```

```html
<div id="scroll" class="scrollable scrollable-y tabs-tab chatlist-parts active" data-filter-id="0" style="">
  <div class="chatlist-top">
    <ul class="chatlist" data-autonomous="0">
      <a class="chatlist-chat rp is-muted" href="#5621107071" data-peer-id="5621107071">
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to pass a URL or path to `load()` for it to retrieve HTML content from. It will then inject that HTML in to the element you specify, `#scroll` in this case. As you've not given it a URL, it's not loading any content so just replaces the content of the element with nothing. What behaviour are you expecting to see?

Comment: Thanks Rory, but actually I did. I tested this:  $("#scroll").load("url #scroll"); and any other type of load method and again that area is blank.

Comment: Well firstly, the URL would need to be absolute: `.load('https://web.telegram.org/k')`, and secondly, and more importantly, as **that's a cross-domain request then it's not going to work**. You'll be blocked by the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). If you want to scrape remote content from another site you would need to do it server side.

Comment: Also note that your HTML is invalid - only `li` can be children of a `ul`, not `a` elements.

Comment: I installed an "no-cores" unblock extension for chrome and try again: no luck!

Comment: Check your dev tools console for errors.

Comment: But this happens in telegram web and I see the <a>s inside of <li>.

Comment: Exactly - inside of `li`, not `ul`.

Comment: No error and problem persists.

Comment: Would you please answer to this my question. Its related to this. I'm Working for 10 hours on this.

Comment: If you check the network tab in devtools can you see the request being made to telegram.org? If so, what's the response text?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73616988/refresh-a-div-property-after-every-execution

Comment: Currently, there's no way to answer the problem as there's not enough debugging information. The original issue was related to the syntax you used, then CORS which you fixed with the Chrome extension. Now there's no error, but you state it's not working. Without information to debug we can't help.

Comment: m.fn.init [div#abc4.sidebar-content.transition.zoom-fade, context: document, selector: '#scroll']
logger.ts:134 [11518.360] [SW] window connected 3f9f9919-f390-4734-9485-796ffe2efb12 windows before 1
logger.ts:134 [11518.360] [SW] windows [Array(2)]

Comment: These reports are shown in console and after the scrollable area turns to blank.